# Lots of long running cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have about 35 cron jobs right now.  Most of them are PHP scripts that either scrape or do some calculations. The scripts also loop over 10-20 different servers to do those scrapes.  (They are different countries so they have to be separate calls).

So we have 30 scripts, each has a loop over 20 servers and therefore take about 5-15 minutes to run per script. I have each script spaced out right now.

But is it better to have 80 individual scripts run instead of 35 scripts that loop and take a while? Each script would take maybe 1-2 minutes instead of 10-15min.

That would of course spawn a ton more PHP processes.  Is there any issue or limit with 10-15 or more PHP processes running at once?

I'm running a cloud server performance on Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if the jobs need to complete in a certain order I would make it as linear as possible.....it might take longer but I always err  . The side of data accuracy.

Comment: Yea i'm aiming for accuracy here, but the scripts are all independent, even the ones in a loop.  Each long running loop is like a black hole though, sometimes 1/20 fails and it's hard to track down.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are creating more processes that will be running at the same time you are going to increase your overall memory footprint.  Each process will carry it's own overhead of memory for the process to run, and to load any libraries needed for it's process. (aside from whatever it needs to do whatever it does).  You will also more than have twice as many script to monitor that they are successfully running all the time.

However in creating more processes you will be able to speed things us since you are essentially creating a multi-thread.  Allowing one process to continue while another is blocking waiting for i/o.

If each script doesn't have a dependency on another, breaking them into smaller scripts should be fine.  If you can handle monitoring more scripts, and the server can handle it, then I would do it.

If scripts do have dependencies, or if you would have to run so many at the same time you server usage maxes out, keep them together.

That being said, I would also try to optimize the script, make sure there isn't something you can do to make them faster without create more processes.

Comment: As far as you know, there isn't a ini config for number of PHP procs that can be spawned? I'm running PHP5-fpm behind nginx. The scripts don't depend on each other. They do load libs though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have the servers setup, I would run them at once. In addition, I would also run them at night, off hours when the web servers aren't in use and not during business operations unless your web app depends on it. If you're on a Cloud server on Rackspace I wouldn't worry about bandwidth although increasing your ram could be an issue further down the road.

Spawning a ton more PHP process shouldn't be a worry if you have sufficient amount of ram; there is no limitation on the linux side.

```
a) Figure out which cron needs to run in which order
b) Order the cron to be run at night, around mid-night
c) Run and fireoff the 80 scripts at once
```

it would also be a good idea to send you an email with cron results or report that it all went through successfully, based on the batch but not individual cron.

Comment: As far as you know, there isn't a ini config for number of PHP procs that can be spawned? I'm running PHP5-fpm behind nginx.

Comment: its not limited, in one of my server there is over 80 httpd processes running on a suped up cloud server on aws ec2 (large.1)